# openrowset ("msdasql") link server with visual fox pro to sql server 2008 is not working in windows 10 64 bit

Tags: sql-server, vb6

i am managing a program which is made with vb6.The scenario is the program is fully working in windows xp and windows 7 but when the program is run in windows 10 ,i got this error  and i have a problem with this code

```
OpenDBF = "openrowset('msdasql',
'driver={microsoft visual foxpro driver};sourcetype=dbf;sourcedb=" + 
gDatadir + ";','" + sQuery + "')"
```

the program used openrowset to link with microsoft visual fox pro .

and the error message is

[image]

please guide me on what to do , THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: Did it work before? What has changed?

Comment: yes its working before actually its 10 years working but when windows 10 updated it suddenly not working and i search for almost a day but i got no idea from the internet

Comment: Win 10 installed yet another update or the computer got "updated" to Win 10? You need to provide more info if you want help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This looks like an SQL Server error to me.

Comment: @Alex ok sir im sorry, first the program is used in windows xp and windows 7 its ok but then when the clients used windows 10 because they upgraded theyre os ,the program is not running anymore actually its working with windows 7 below sir .

Comment: Please read How To Ask link above and add update your question to include additional information. Remember, we know nothing about your application, only that what you tell us. (A possible issue maybe the bitness, i.e. 32-bit vs 64-bit OS, where FoxPro 64-bit driver does not exist)

Comment: done sir! thank you for advising me